# Can't get gameobject to move

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm trying to make a simulation of our marching band show, and I can't seem to get my character to move. I made a script that will calculate the time it will take based on how many counts it takes and the tempo of the song.

Here's [my script](http://pastebin.com/UQTKCZMG) on the character so far:

```
#pragma strict
var targetx : int;
var targetz : int;
var counts : int;
var tempo : int;
private var speed : int;

function Start () {

}

function Update () {
        var y = 1.5;
        var speed = (1/(tempo/2))*counts;
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(Vector3(gameObject.transform.position.x, y, gameObject.transform.position.z), Vector3(targetx, y, targetz), speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I'm putting the variables in in the inspector.

EDIT: I figured it out, I used var speed = (1/(tempo/2))*counts; instead of just speed.

Comment: Can you put your code in the post? Just paste it in, highlight it, and click the "code" button.

Comment: I copy-pasted the code to my project, attached it to a object and the object moves as expected. What do you set in Inspector for `targetx`, `targetz`, `counts` and `tempo`? Consider using `Debug.Log()`  in yout `Update()` method to see these values, like this `Debug.Log("targetx: " + targetx + ", targetz: " + targetz + ", counts: " + counts + ", tempo: " + tempo);`. You can see the output of `Debug.Log()` in Console, which can be shown in editor via menu `Window->Console`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your speed variable is private, and not initialized with a value. So, the value of speed is defaulted to 0. Try changing it to something like

```
private var speed : int = 5;
```

Comment: That should not matter much as the class' `speed` variable is subsequently hidden by the local `speed` variable of the Update function.